# Sharepoint (2010) Diagnostic Studio lists "Others" users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performance, site-usage, diagnostics

I recently downloaded and ran this tool called Sharepoint Diagnostic Studio and when I run the report to see requests per user I get the below:

[image]

What would the "Others" UserLogin be referring to? How can I check what these are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144782(v=office.14).aspx

It looks as though that may point to the service accounts such as search/content, and the web application pool accounts.

> Requests Per User
>
> This report displays the percentage of requests made by the most
>   common user accounts. Some system accounts, such as the search crawler
>   service account, might be expected to generate many requests. At
>   certain times, individual users might also perform operations that
>   create an unexpected peak in resource usage.

Comment: Yes, I thought this might be the case but wanted to check anyway. Thanks.